# Implicits and order of declaration

Tags: scala, implicit

Here is a simplification of what I encountered. This compiles:

```
trait A { implicit val x = 1 }
trait B extends A { val y = implicitly[Int] }
```

While this don't (could not find implicit value):

```
trait B extends A { val y = implicitly[Int] }
trait A { implicit val x = 1 }
```

I tried to make my intentions clear by specifying a self-type: `trait A { this: B => ... }`, but to no avail.

How do I deal with this kind of dependencies without worrying about how my code is laid out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to declare the type explicitly, at least for the latter one

```
trait B extends A { val y = implicitly[Int] }
trait A { implicit val x : Int = 1 }
```

The rules for implicit visibility is different whether its type is declared explicitely or not. If it is not, the implicit is available (as an implicit)  only after the point of declaration.

The reason is that type inference may become too difficult if the type was not declared (as in recursive routine). In many cases, inference would be easy (as in your code) but the spec has to be clear cut.

Comment: What about implicit objects? Could you point me to the parts of spec regarding resolution of implicits? `trait X; trait B extends A { val y = implicitly[X] }; trait A { implicit object x extends X }`

Comment: Sorry for late answer. After a more than cursory look in the spec, I could not find the rule. It is mentionned however in [this bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-801), look like it is what the implementation does, but it has not yet made it to the spec. I don't understand why it should not work with an implicit object.